# Migration from Ubuntu to Mint

Tags: home-directory, mint, migration

I'd like to migrate from Ubuntu 12.10 to Mint 14, but it's important that I keep everything which is in my `/home` directory. Will it work if I just put the directory on a USB stick, then replace the default one by ny old one after the install is complete (I'll use the same username/paaswd on the new install)?

Comment: Mint is [off-topic on this site](http://askubuntu.com/faq). You might want to ask on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.  I'd use something like tar (there are other options, rsync, cp, cpio):

```
cd /media/usb-stick/
tar -pcvzf home.$USER.tar.gz /home/$USER
```

To unpack on new computer:

```
cd /
tar -xvzf /media/usb-stick/home.$USER.tar.gz
```

If you have any permission problems after, do this:

```
# own everything in your home dir by you.  This is usually safe/correct,
# unless you have some unusual permissions set up somewhere (like a directory
# for sharing files with other users on the system) 
chown -R $USER:$USER ~
```

Some problems you may run into:

- Disk Space: make sure your usb stick has enough space
- File size too big:  If your home directory has more than 2G of files, you might create a file too big for a fat32 usb-stick.  Either format it ext3, tar up partial directories, copy in batches or use another method to archive things (rsync, network copy it, etc)
- if you don't use tar, and use cp or rsync, you need to copy to a unix filesystem, like ext3.  Copying to a fat usb-disk without using tar will mess up permissions.
- dot files: make sure if you do partial directories, you don't forget all the files in your home directory that start with a dot (hidden).

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't do it. It will be safer to save your data & do a clean install. There's no guarantee that the config files will match & that could create conflicts.

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is to use **cinnamon** instead of migrating to mint

http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/09/20/install-cinnamon-1-6-in-ubuntu-12-04-lts/

Cinnamon 1.6, the latest edition of the desktop environment whose development was partly inspired by popular dissatisfaction with Unity and GNOME 3 was released yesterday. It is a project from the developers of Linux Mint, a desktop distribution derived from Ubuntu.

As a Free Software desktop environment and project, you can install it on any distribution, provided there is a binary package for it. Without that, you can compile it from source, if doing business at the command-line does not scare you.

**Ubuntu Cinnamon PPA**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-stable

sudo apt-get update 

sudo apt-get install cinnamon
```